# Why does my JavaFX window look different everywhere?

Tags: java, javafx

I was playing around with JavaFX. In Scene Builder and when run by Eclipse, it looks like this:

[image]

When, I exported it as a Runnable Jar. Placed it in my desktop, and this is what I get:

[image]

Why?

I am on Mac OSX, using Java 7.

This is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
  <children>
    <TabPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
      <tabs>
        <Tab text="Untitled Tab 1">
          <content>
            <AnchorPane id="Content" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
              <children>
                <Button layoutX="103.0" layoutY="65.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
                <Button layoutX="103.0" layoutY="110.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="121.0" text="Button" />
                <CheckBox layoutX="103.0" layoutY="166.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="CheckBox" />
                <ChoiceBox layoutX="103.0" layoutY="201.0">
                  <items>
                    <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                      <String fx:value="Item 1" />
                      <String fx:value="Item 2" />
                      <String fx:value="Item 3" />
                    </FXCollections>
                  </items>
                </ChoiceBox>
                <MenuBar prefWidth="600.0">
                  <menus>
                    <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                      <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
                      </items>
                    </Menu>
                    <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
                      <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
                      </items>
                    </Menu>
                    <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
                      <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                      </items>
                    </Menu>
                  </menus>
                </MenuBar>
                <ProgressBar layoutX="100.0" layoutY="249.0" prefWidth="200.0" progress="0.45" />
                <ProgressIndicator layoutX="397.0" layoutY="99.0" prefHeight="113.0" prefWidth="131.0" progress="-0.43" />
                <RadioButton layoutX="348.0" layoutY="247.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="RadioButton" />
              </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          </content>
        </Tab>
        <Tab text="Untitled Tab 2">
          <content>
            <AnchorPane id="Content" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
          </content>
        </Tab>
      </tabs>
    </TabPane>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's using different JVM versions in different contexts. It looks like you have SceneBuilder and Eclipse configured to use Java 7 with JavaFX 2.2, but you have Java 8 installed as the default JVM on your Mac; so when you run the jar file it is running under Java 8.

To check this, open up terminal and type `java -version`. I expect you will get a Java 8 version.

JavaFX 2.2 and Java 8 use different default stylesheets. JavaFX 2.2 uses caspian.css, whereas Java 8 uses modena.css. Try running your executable jar file from the Terminal with the following option:

```
java -Djavafx.userAgentStylesheetUrl=caspian -jar path/to/jar/file
```

and it should look (almost exactly) like it does in JavaFX 2.2

Comment: You can also set stylesheet programmaticaly by executing `Application.setUserAgentStylesheet(Application.STYLESHEET_CASPIAN);` or `Application.setUserAgentStylesheet(Application.STYLESHEET_MODENA);`

Comment: Your command line indeed works, but `java -version` yields `1.7.0_51`, which is guess is Java 7. It's true that I once did have Java 8, but I removed it. Anyway, is there a way to force caspian in my code? Modena doesn't seem to be working well in my system - for instance, the progress bar doesn't animate (maybe because I removed Java 8)

Comment: Yes, something is somehow weird, as it's clearly using modena by default. To force it to use caspian in the code, in a way that works in Java 7, just try setting the system property: `System.setProperty("javax.userAgentStylesheetUrl", "caspian");` You can do that at the beginning of the `start(...)` method.

Comment: Thank you, works great. Think you meant javafx instead of javax though.

Comment: Yes indeed. Apologies for typo.